Lista por compresión anidada en Python
Dada la matriz:
matriz = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 10, 11, 12],
    ]

Para recorrerla valor por valor he usado un doble bucle for:
for i in range(len(matriz)):
    for j in range(len(matriz[0])):
        print(matriz[i][j], end=" ")
    print()

He tratado de pasar está función a una lista por compresión, pero con escaso éxito:
[print(matriz[i][j], end=" ") for i in range(len(matriz)) for j in range(len(matriz[0]))]

Pero la salida no es la que esperaba:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

¿Es posible pasar la función a una lista por compresión produciendo la misma salida?
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
10 11 12

Gracias

Simplemente no uses las listas por compresión para esto, es mucho más ineficiente y menos legible que usar ciclos for normales. Y la razón es muy simple, no necesitas una nueva lista, solo imprimir.
Para empezar generas una lista con las salidas de print(), una lista de Nones que no sirve para nada más que para ocupar memoria y gastar ciclos de CPU...
Es un error común forzar el uso de listas por compresión en substitución de ciclos for en la idea de que son más eficientes. Efectivamente son más eficientes a la hora de generar una nueva lista en contraposición a iterar con ciclos "normales" + list.append(). No obstante, hay casos donde es todo lo contrario, este es un ejemplo ilustrativo  de ello, terminas creando un nuevo objeto list que no tiene utilidad.
Lo que hace las listas por compresión más eficientes es el prescindir de repetidas llamadas a list.append(), aparte de otras optimizaciones que se pueden hacer al crear la lista a nivel de C de una sola vez.
Por ejemplo, una forma mucho más simple y eficiente de obtener la misma salida que quieres es:
for row in matriz:
    print(*row)

*row simplemente desempaqueta el iterable (la sublista de cada fila en este caso) como argumentos posicionales de la función, print() en este caso. Es decir:
lista = [1, 2, 3]
print(*lista)

equivaldría a:
lista = [1, 2, 3]
print(lista[0], lista[1], lista[2])

Otra observación, en Python evita indizar si no es necesario (generalmente para asignar nuevos valores a una posición). Iterar directamente con un for in es más legible y más eficiente, es decir, en vez de:
for i in range(len(matriz)):
    for j in range(len(matriz[0])):
        item = matriz[i][j]
        ...

simplemente:
for fila in matriz:
    for item in fila:
        ...

Si insistes en usar una "solución de una línea" siempre puedes recurrir a algo como:
print(*(" ".join(str(item) for item in row) for row in matriz), sep="\n")

o:
print(*(" ".join(map(str, row)) for row in matriz), sep="\n")

que usa str.join() y un generador por compresión para generar cada linea. Pero es menos legible y más ineficiente que el simple ciclo for anterior.

Muchas gracias, ha sido muy instructivo
